# How to bind model data to Aurelia route in router config

Tags: aurelia

Suppose I have following 2 routes configurations that are using same module `./foo.html`:

```
export class App {
  configureRouter(config, router) {
    config.map([
      {route: 'foo1', name: 'foo1', moduleId: './foo.html', nav: true, title: 'Foo1'},
      {route: 'foo2', name: 'foo2', moduleId: './foo.html', nav: true, title: 'Foo2'}
    ]);
  }
}
```

And I have `foo.html` custom element:

```
<template bindable="grade">
  ${grade}
</template>
```

Then, **how can I bind `{grade: 'A'}` model to `foo1` route and bind `{grade: 'B'}` model to `foo2` route?**

I was expecting that there is something like `model` property that I can bind my model to each route like the following:

```
{route: 'foo1', name: 'foo1', moduleId: './foo.html', model:{grade: 'A'}, nav: true, title: 'Foo1'},
 {route: 'foo2', name: 'foo2', moduleId: './foo.html', model:{grade: 'B'}, nav: true, title: 'Foo2'}
```

But this didn't work.

---

Note, I don't want to pass any data via `settings` property of a route config because I will lose some advantages that comes with `bindable` technique. For example, the above `foo` html-component can be reused as an element in html view:

```
<div>
  blah blah
  <foo grade.bind="'C'"></foo>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a route paramater to your route, like so:

```
config.map([
    {route: 'foo/:grade', name: 'foo', moduleId: './foo', nav: true, title: 'Foo'}
]);
```

Then access it using the following:

```
import { autoinject } from "aurelia-dependency-injection";
import { Router } from "aurelia-routing";

@autoinject()
export Foo {
  grade: string;

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  attached () {
    this.grade = this.router.currentInstruction.params.grade;
  }
}
```

Comment: Passing `grade` data via route address `'foo/:grade'` will expose the data. Also, passing type other than string, like number, boolean, array or object will not be possible.

Comment: You can always parse to a number or boolean, but I understand your concern. I don't quite see what you wish to achieve but I hope someone else finds something useful.